# Showing two Reports data in single crystal Report

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I am trying to show tables in one crystal report just like:

```
Table A========================================================================
ColA      ColB     Colc       ColD




Table B========================================================================
ColA      ColB     Colc       ColD
```

and both are independent of each other, how to achieve the same display and result?
I have created Table A and is displayed, but do I inserted a sub-report, but by inserting the same I am not getting the desired result.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: I am fine with the databinding concept I just want to know the procedure to display two reports one after another.

Comment: Did you try to create two sun report and then add to a master report. this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to accomplish what you're trying to do is with subreports (also suggested by Hiten004 in the comments).  Simply insert two subreports into the main report - the first one will connect to table A and the second will connect to table B.

In order to get them to display from your main report, make sure they are not configured as "on demand" subreports.

To save time if the formatting needs to look the same for the two reports, consider designing the subreport as its own report first (with datasource A), saving it, then importing it twice.  Once imported, just change the datasource of the second subreport to datasource B using the "Set Table Location" feature.